# RPM issues after signing JDK 1.6 64-bit

Tags: centos, rpm, public-key, gpg, digital-signatures

I'm trying to sign the Java JDK 1.6u21 64-bit RPM on CentOS 5.5 for use with Spacewalk and I'm running into problems. It seems to sign okay, but then when I check the signature it seems to be missing the key I just used to sign it. Yet RPM shows the key in it's list...

```
# rpm --addsign jdk-6u21-linux-amd64.rpm 
Enter pass phrase: 
Pass phrase is good.
jdk-6u21-linux-amd64.rpm:
gpg: WARNING: standard input reopened
gpg: WARNING: standard input reopened

# rpm --checksig -v jdk-6u21-linux-amd64.rpm 
    jdk-6u21-linux-amd64.rpm:
    Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID ecfd98a5
    MD5 digest: OK (650e0961e20d4a44169b68e8f4a1691b)
    V3 DSA signature: OK, key ID ecfd98a5
```

Yet I have the key imported (edited for privacy):

```
# rpm -qa gpg-pubkey* |grep ecfd98a5
gpg-pubkey-ecfd98a5-4caa4a4c
# rpm -qi gpg-pubkey-ecfd98a5-4caa4a4c
Name        : gpg-pubkey                   Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : ecfd98a5                          Vendor: (none)
Release     : 4caa4a4c                      Build Date: Mon 04 Oct 2010 10:20:49 PM CDT
Install Date: Mon 04 Oct 2010 10:20:49 PM CDT      Build Host: localhost
Group       : Public Keys                   Source RPM: (none)
Size        : 0                                License: pubkey
Signature   : (none)
Summary     : gpg(FirstName LastName <myemail@example.com>)
Description :
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: rpm-4.4.2.3 (NSS-3)
...key goes here...
=gKjN-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

And I'm definitely running a 64-bit version of CentOS:

```
# uname -a
Linux spacewalk.mycompany.corp 2.6.18-194.11.4.el5 #1 SMP Tue Sep 21 05:04:09 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Without a valid signature, Spacewalk refuses to install the RPM unless I completely disable signature checking. I have tried this with two different keys and two different users on the same machine without any success.

Any bright ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your checksig output is correct since it shows your public key ID.

Are you doing this between two machines or all on one?

Comment: The output I included was all from one machine, although I reproduce the problem on any of our other CentOS machines.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug with large RPMs in RHEL/CentOS 5 that causes GPG sigs to always fail for some large RPMs.

Comment: Any known work around? Any idea what size constitutes "large"?